# Matrix transpose in Ryacas

Tags: r, symbolic-math

The transpose operator does not seem to work when used on a symbolic matrix
created using Ryacas.

```
> library(Ryacas)
Loading required package: XML
> 
> u=Sym("u")
> v=Sym("v")
> w=Sym("w")
> DG=List(List(w-v), List(u-w), List(v-u))
> PrettyForm(DG)
[1] "Starting Yacas!"
Accepting requests from port 9734
/            \
| ( w - v )  |
|            |
| ( u - w )  |
|            |
| ( v - u )  |
\            /
> DGT=t(DG)
> PrettyForm(DGT)
/            \
| ( w - v )  |
|            |
| ( u - w )  |
|            |
| ( v - u )  |
\            /
> DG
{{w-v},{u-w},{v-u}};
> DGT
{{w-v},{u-w},{v-u}};
>
```

I was expecting DGT to be a 1 x 3 row vector.

Answer (score 0):

Ryacas does not provide it.  Try this:

```
t.Sym <- function(x) Sym("Transpose(", x, ")")
PrettyForm(t(DG))
```