# Ryacas substitute but don't simplify or evaluate

Tags: r, eval, substitution, yacas

I am using the Ryacas package in R and am trying to substitute variables for values but not simplify or solve the equation to show the working out. I have searched Stackoverflow, read the Ryacas documentation and have attempted to find this in the Yacas manual but have so far come up short. I think I am looking to turn simplification off to get the substituted equation and then on again to provide the final result.

Here is an example which provides only the result rather than the working:

```
library(Ryacas)
# a <- 2
# b <- 3
# c <- 4
eq <- ysym(('(a * b) / c'))

solution <- with_value(with_value(with_value(eq, 'a', 2), 'b', 3), 'c', 4)
tex(solution)
# "\\frac{3}{2}"
```

What I am trying to get as an output is:

```
# working out
# "\\frac{2 \times 3}{4}
```

as well as the actual solution:

```
# solution
# "\\frac{3}{2}"
```

Does anyone know whether there is a solution to this problem such as passing a command to yacas through `yac_str` or similar. I have tried translating to latex using the `tex()` command and then substituting after though the multiplication operators are removed and this means I need to find and replace them which becomes nasty when dealing with symbolics:

```
tex(eq)
# "\\frac{a b}{c}"

# substituting string values using stringi requires additional  
# work to deal with the missing `*` between `a` and `b`
# "\\frac{2 3}{4}"
```

Whilst this can be done for simple expressions, there are numerous exceptions such as the variables `a` and `c` being present in `\\frac` etc.

I have also tried the `TexForm` command and `substitute` in various guises but am still not able to capture the unsimplified and unevaluated equation:

```
y_fn(substitute(with_value(eq, 'a', 2)), "TeXForm")
# "\\frac{2 b}{c}"

eval(substitute(with_value(eval(substitute(with_value(eq, 'a', 2))), 'b', 3)))
# y: 6/c
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to customize this some more but this general approach can work if you are willing to do that.

We translate words to their values using gsubfn and handle the \times part at the end with gsub.  Note that frac is not modified because we are matching words and frac it is not a word in the list given in the second arg to gsubfn.

```
library(magrittr)
library(gsubfn)
library(Ryacas)

eq <- ysym(('(a * b) / c'))

eq %>%
  tex %>%
  gsubfn("(\\w+)", list(a = 2, b = 3, c = 4), .) %>%
  gsub("(\\d) (\\d)", "\\1 \\\\times \\2", .)
## [1] "\\frac{2 \\times 3}{4}"
```

### Added

Take the first three code examples when searching for [r] Ryacas in stackoverflow and it worked on all of them.  Note that these used the  original version of Ryacas which is currently called Ryacas0 so I used that.

```
library(Ryacas0)
library(gsubfn)
library(magrittr)

tex_sub <- function(.x, ...) {
  .x %>%
    gsubfn("(\\w+)", list(...), .) %>%
    gsub("(\\d) (\\d)", "\\1 \\\\times \\2", .)
}

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858668/symbolic-matrix-multiplication-by-ryacas
x <- Sym("x")
mat1 <- List(
  List(x, 2),
  List(x^3, x))

mat2 <- List(
  List(x, x),
  List(3, 6 * x))

tt <- TeXForm(mat1 * mat2)
tex_sub(tt, x = 1)

###

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739173/matrix-transpose-in-ryacas
u=Sym("u")
v=Sym("v")
w=Sym("w")
DG=List(List(w-v), List(u-w), List(v-u))
tt2 <- TeXForm(DG)
tex_sub(tt2, u = 2, v = 3, w = 4)

###

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572184/how-to-derivate-using-ryacas

x <- Sym("x")
P <- Sym(1)
for (k in 1:3) {
  P <- Simplify((1+k*x)*P + x*(1-x)*deriv(P, x))
  print(P)
}
tt3 <- TeXForm(P)
tex_sub(tt3, x = 10)
```

Comment: Is not really possibly to suspend the evaluation of expressions in `ryacas`, @G.Grothendieck? That would be a more general approach.

Comment: If that is not possible, maybe `sympy` (`Python`) could be used via `reticulate` (or even `R::caracas`). Function `sympy::sympify` has a flag `evaluate=False`.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck, thanks for the code which does answer the specific problem posed. As @Paul Smith has mentioned, this is not a general approach which could apply to more complex equations. I think I will need to check the `caracas` package

Comment: I think you underestimating the generality. I took the first three code examples from stackoverflow (see Added section) which include fairly complex formulas and it worked on all of them.  Also I think you are overestimating the generality of the approach you are siuggesting since, for example, you would want \times in the substituted version but not in the non-substituted version so its not really that general.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck, thank you for the additional post. I believe your solution fully solves the problem which I did not fully understand at first